# Scripting a .write script containing HTML tags using only double quotes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tricky situation where one set of rules conflicts with another over specifications of banners.

One spec details that single quotes are not allowed, and the other has a script which is *essential* to the banner. Without the script, there is no point serving the banner in the first place.

So the question is, is there a way to write this script using **only** double quotes?

```
<script>
    document.write('<script src="' + (window.API_URL || 'http://example.com/' + Math.random()) + '"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: `"` -> `\'`...?  Now you've edited, inverse all your quotes, then do `'` -> `\"`?

Comment: Try to avoid using `document.write` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: Also, document write does overwrite the whole document. you need to append it to the head.

Comment: @nicael - no it does not overwrite if the script is inline as it is in this case

Comment: @mplungjan something new today, thanks :D

Comment: @nicael You are correct when it is executed after load like `function writeIt() { document.write..... } .... window.onload=writeIt;` That would wipe the page

Comment: @mplungjan yeah thx this is what I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just escape the double quotes that you *don't* want to terminate the string? `\"` evaluates to the literal character `"`.

```
document.write("<script src=\"" + (window.API_URL || "http://example.com/" + Math.random()) + "\"><\/script>');
```

Comment: Because the answer seems to be quite obvious, right? There's no question even.

Comment: That's barely even a valid reason to vote down a question, let alone a correct answer.

Comment: It's barely a reason not to downvote. Also, has been asked bunch of times.